# Validaton loss decrease and validation accuracy decrease in CNN classification

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification, loss-function

Im training classification on 2 classes (spawned fish or not from image of scale). The dataset is unbalanced. There is only 5% spawned scales.

I havnt checked how many spawned fish are in each of train/validation/test sets, but there are 9073 images. Splitt in 70/15/15 %. Then I observe in epoke 2 that val_loss decrease while val_acc decrease. How is that possible?

Im using Keras. The network is EfficientNetB4 from github.com/qubvel.

```py
1600/1600 [==============================] - 1557s 973ms/step - loss: 1.3353 - acc: 0.6474 - val_loss: 0.8055 - val_acc: 0.7046

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.80548, saving model to ./checkpoints_missing_loss2/salmon_scale_inception.001-0.81.hdf5
Epoch 2/150
1600/1600 [==============================] - 1508s 943ms/step - loss: 0.8013 - acc: 0.7084 - val_loss: 0.6816 - val_acc: 0.6973

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.80548 to 0.68164, saving model to ./checkpoints_missing_loss2/salmon_scale_inception.002-0.68.hdf5
```

Edit: here is another example - only 1010 images but its balanced - 50/50.

```py
Epoch 5/150
1600/1600 [==============================] - 1562s 976ms/step - loss: 0.0219 - acc: 0.9933 - val_loss: 0.2639 - val_acc: 0.9605

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 0.28715 to 0.26390, saving model to ./checkpoints_missing_loss2/salmon_scale_inception.005-0.26.hdf5
Epoch 6/150
1600/1600 [==============================] - 1565s 978ms/step - loss: 0.0059 - acc: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.4140 - val_acc: 0.9276

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.26390
Epoch 7/150
1600/1600 [==============================] - 1561s 976ms/step - loss: 0.0180 - acc: 0.9941 - val_loss: 0.2379 - val_acc: 0.9276
```

and val_loss decrease aswell as val_acc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such an unbalanced dataset, the model first classifies everything as the majority class which gets relatively high accuracy, but all probability is distributed to the majority class. The reason is that the final bias can be learned very quickly because the back-propagation path is very short.

In the later stages of the training, the model basically finds reasons not to classify the input with the majority class. At this point, the model starts to make mistakes, the accuracy goes down, but the probability is more evenly distributed, so from the loss perspective, the error is smaller.

With such an imbalanced dataset, I would rather track F-measure instead of accuracy.

Comment: Yes, I calculate Precsision, recall, and F1 on the test-set but there are no F measures in keras - so accuracy is convenient.

Comment: question is downvoted to oblivion, but I found another example where the dataset is balanced - but small - where val_loss and val_acc decrease.